# chrome extension: Storing and accessing larger character list across domains

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm writing my first chrome extension. Here's what I am trying to do:

The extension is supposed to make it easier to learn Chinese characters. The idea is that the user can highlight a Chinese character that he already knows on one website  and then when he visits another website from another domain, all characters that he previously marked are highlighted.(So characterlist should be persistent and around max 1000 characters);

I got it working with a content script ,an array and localStorage:

```
localStorage.hanzimarker= JSON.stringify(characterlist);
```

However because of the security policies it doesn't work across different websites. As each domain as it's on local storage (if I save the web pages to the local file system or for pages of the same domain it works).

Is there a way around this? Maybe with the localstorage of a background page? My first Idea was to write the character list to a text file and parse it later, but this is also not allowed as I understood. Or is there another type of storage that doesn't have this limitation?

Comment: Yes, you can use `chrome.storage` http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody runs into the same problem:
rsanchez's hint was right:
use http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
default_list = ['a','b','c'];

storage.set({'test':default_list},function(){
    console.log('test written');
});
storage.get('test', function(content){

    console.log('test read content', content.test);
});
```

unlike localstorage it is asynchronous so you have to put a callback where the console.log calls are in my example.
And it works with objects.